# Using reledmac, and referring to page and line numbers outside the \beginnumbering

Tags: cross-referencing, line-numbering, reledmac

Perhaps this is something handled by a different package from reledmac. I have the text and critical apparatus as footnotes. Now I would like to be able to refer to the line and page numbers of the text elsewhere in the document -- for instance, in the introduction, I might want to say "This scene begins on line X of page Y" or "See line X of page Y for an example." I also think that to make an extensive commentary after the text, it would be easier to do it separately than to use the \AEndnote command.

Do I need to use a different package in combination with reledmac to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

reledmac provides tools for that.

First, you must mark your line

```
\edlabel{yourlabel}
```

Then you can use

```
see p. \edpageref{yourlabel} l \edlineref{yourlabel}
```

It also provides

```
\edlabelS{yourlabel}…\edlabelE{yourlabel}
```

That allow you to marks the begin / the end of a passage and to use command like

```
\SEref{yourlabel}
\SErefwithpage{yourlabel}
```

Which automatically insert starting/end lines if they differs.

Please read § 11 of reledmac handbook for more details

Comment: Thank you! That's very simple. Thank you for making a great package and if this project ever is published I will give you credit in the acknowledgements.

Comment: your'e welcome. please don't forget to validate the answer, and not just to  vote up it.