# Labelling a word outside the apparatus in reledmac with \linenumberstyle{alph}

Tags: labels, line-numbering, reledmac

I would ask if it is possible to label a word in order to show his line number outside the apparatus in reledmac package, like is explained here [Using reledmac, and referring to page and line numbers outside the \beginnumbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321807/using-reledmac-and-referring-to-page-and-line-numbers-outside-the-beginnumberi), but using alphabetic numbering. Currently it refers to the relative label with an arabic number, altough the lineation style is set to alphabetic with `\linenumberstyle{alph}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, draft]{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}


\linenumberstyle{alph}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}

\beginnumbering
\pstart

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor\edlabel{tempor} incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat

\pend
\pausenumbering


\edlineref{tempor} tempor %note that it gives "2", not "b" as intended.


\end{document}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: that is obviously a bug, that I will solve quickly.

Comment: I also noted that using \edlabelS{yourlabel}…\edlabelE{yourlabel} and \SEref{yourlabel} gives the correct alphabetic lineation

Comment: yes, because that call the macro used to print the line number in critical footnote.

Comment: I have fixed the bug on my computer. I have just to do changelog and to submit it to CTAN, this afternoon, after eating.

Comment: Great! Helpful and timely as always! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just send on CTAN a v.2.16.6 of reledmac and v2.14.4 of reledpar, which fix this problem.

Comment: I downloaded the new version and it works correctly as intended. Thank you!